# Android persitence between Ondraw calls

Tags: android, canvas, ondraw

In my android application I am drawing a graph which has a large quantity of data, I need to plot the data and then plot more data over the top of it. Rather then storing all the data and redrawing with every ondraw call is there any way of having persistence between calls to ondraw, it seems that ondraw always expects the data to be re-drawn.

Answer (score 0):

Just draw all your data on a `Bitmap` and then draw this bitmap in `onDraw()`